# cross hairs in python animation

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

So I'm doing some animation using matplotlib.animation.  All the graphics that I'm plotting have been circles, but one of my circles has gotten too small as I keep on making things more complex.  I was looking around trying to find out if pyplot has a cross hairs command like pyplot.Circle, but I was unsuccessful.  Anyone out there know of something like this that is built in to pyplot or do I have to build my own function that does that?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're wanting.  Do you want interactive "cross hairs"? If so, have a look at: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/cursor.html  If you want to make a static "cross hair", have a look at `axhline` and `axvline`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you're asking.

As I'm currently reading your question, I can't tell which of these options you're asking for.

1. Interactive "cross hairs" that move with the mouse.
2. A static "cross hair" that extends across the axis.
3. A "+" style marker to be placed instead of a circle.

---

For the first option, have a look at `matplotlib.widgets.Cursor`. There's an example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/cursor.html

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#FFFFCC')

x, y = 4*(np.random.rand(2, 100)-.5)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

# set useblit = True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2 )

plt.show()
```

---

For the second, use `axhline` and `axvline`.  E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cross_hair(x, y, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    horiz = ax.axhline(y, **kwargs)
    vert = ax.axvline(x, **kwargs)
    return horiz, vert

cross_hair(0.2, 0.3, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Finally, if you want a `+` marker in place of a circle, just use either use `ax.plot` or `ax.scatter`.

E.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
marker, = ax.plot([0.2], [0.3], linestyle='none', marker='+')
```

Or:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
marker = ax.scatter([0.2], [0.3], marker='+')
```

[image]

You can manually build the marker (it's easiest to use `Line2D`, but you can also use `matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle('+').get_path()` to get a raw path and then set the position and size to suit), but it's usually far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Sorry for me being vague the third solution is what I wanted.  Thanks